# Adding a navbar to a Boostrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/) to the left of a Bootstrap modal window.

I found that it is easily done when the `navbar` is [hard-coded](http://www.bootply.com/plF8Qdzc0i). However, when adding it dynamically using JQuery, it's a challenge.

My Bootstrap3 modal is as follows and can be found on this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/pk6b7xia29):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">            
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-3 sidebar">
                    <ul id="left_links" class="nav nav-sidebar">

                       <!-- <li> links added dynamically here </li>-->  

                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-9 main">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div id="content"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to add them using:

```
var links = ['main.html','index1.html','index2.html'];
for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++){ 
    // Add links 
    $("#left_links ul").append('<li><a href="#">'+links[i]+'</a></li>'); 

}
```

The CSS I have, so that the modal height is re-adjusted automatically:

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: auto;
    overflow-y:scroll;
 }
```

However, neither are the links appearing nor the modal re-adjusting its height based on the number of links inserted.

Comment: You don't need the `ul` in side the `$('#left_links ul')` - check @Stef answer below - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32996233/3296661

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's just a simple selector issue. Changing `#left_links ul` to `#left_links` works fine in your Bootply.

```
var links = ['main.html','index1.html','index2.html'];
for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++){ 
    // Add links 
    $("#left_links").append('<li><a href="#">'+links[i]+'</a></li>'); 

}
```

Comment: Damn I was typing out my answer, you beat me to it! :P

Comment: @ChrisBeckett Haha I had a feeling this one would be a race so I typed quickly!

Comment: @Stef - Exactly! I was about to press submit, then I saw your answer pop up. Good going :)

Comment: first come first served